# Access VBA tries to terminate return value of Function

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm building an Access database using some VBA code.
I've made a very simple class and a function which creates an instance of that class. Executing this function yields an error 91: object variable or With block variable not set. After debugging I found out Access tries to terminate the newly created object, ending the terminate function results in the error.

My intention was to create a factory for MyObject in order to create an object and initialize it with given arguments. I've stripped all this away to find the problem and now I'm dumbfounded. Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong because I have no idea anymore.

The class I made, called MyObject:

```vb
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    'does literally nothing
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    'does literally nothing
End Sub
```

The function I made to initialize the class, located in another module:

```vb
Public Function createMyObject(someArg As String) As MyObject
    Set createMyObject = New MyObject
End Function
```

I obviously expected the function createMyObject to return an instance of MyObject, but it gives me an error 91. Debugging led me to the Class_Terminate Sub in MyObject where the error gets thrown at the "end sub" line.

Comment: How do you invoke this function when debugging?

Answer (score 0):

Try with using a property:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private mTest As Variant

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    'does literally nothing
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    'does literally nothing
End Sub

Public Property Get Test() As Variant    
    Test = mTest    
End Property

Public Property Let Test(ByVal NewValue As Variant)    
    mTest = NewValue    
End Property
```

and then:

```
Public Function CreateMyObject(SomeArg As String) As MyObject

    Set CreateMyObject = New MyObject
    CreateMyObject.Test = SomeArg

End Function
```

which you can call like this:

```
Set o = CreateMyObject("Joe")
Debug.Print o.Test
```